# Spring data rest is not saving all field of my entity

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have the following @Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Date birthDate;
    private String status;
    private String city;
    ...    
    // many more attributes
}
```

I'm using the spring data rest as follow:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "person", path = "person")
public interface PersonRepositorio extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long>{

}
```

When I send the a post to the `/api/person/` with a JSON containing all attributes of Person, only status is not set. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think you're missing the get and set for status. Did you check it?